# How can I pass params to iterator in for loop?

Tags: python, redis, iterator

How can I pass some parameters to iterator function in for loop?
I want to pass parameter to redis.StrictRedis.get(), like queue.Queue.get()

When using queue.Queue(), I can iter this queue like this.

```py
q = queue.Queue()
for data in iter(q.get, None):
    # some codes...
```

However, when using redis.StrictRedis(), I must pass some arguments like 'key value'.

```py
conn = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=port, db=db)
data = conn.get(key)
```

So how can I pass 'key' value to iter(conn.get, None)?

```py
for data in iter(conn.get, None): # <- here
   # some codes...
```

Comment: what about [`getrange()`](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.Redis.getrange)?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Like `for data in getrange(key, start, end): ...`? However this code run on independent threading.Thread() or multiprocessing.Process() and waiting for data, so I can't know how many datas may pass from redis queue...

Comment: Wrap it in a function which does the job, then pass that function instead. The function will have to obtain `key` in a manner other than via input arguments.